# Declared variables cannot be deleted in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

As per the MDN, Declared variables are a non configurable property of their execution context(function or global). Undeclared variables are configurable(e.g. can be deleted).

When I tried deleting a declared variable using the delete keyword, it got deleted. And same thing happened to undeclared variables.

Has the specification changed? I am using IE9.

Its so confusing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please add a link to the relevant section of the documentation that you are referring to?

Comment: I've not IE9 at hands to test, but in modern browsers this works as the MDN document describes.

Comment: Its 3rd point under Description. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: @Teemu- I tried the same thing in Chromium and it works fine. What on Earth is wrong with IE

Comment: Well, IE has always done things differently from standards (more than other browsers), this seems to be just another exception. When testing IE11, it seems to work as Chrome and FF though.